# How can i handle nested queries with promises instead of callback?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, bluebird

how can i do the following with bluebird promises. modules i am using are `bluebird`, `promise-mysql`

1. insert in table A and return a_id
2. insert records in table B using a_id as foreign key
3. insert records in table C using a_id as foreign key
4. now response is send to user that all records are added.

I am using native queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general idea is:

```
insetA()
  .then(function(a_id){
    return Promise.all([inserB(a_id), inserC(a_id)])
  })
  .then(function(){
     res.send("all good")
  })
  .catch(function(error){
     res.send("some error")
  })


function insetA(){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // inserting A 
    // resolve(a_id)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and saw that functions in `promise-mysql` library return promises. Do you know what that means? You can just chain each and every one of them with `.then()`.

Here is an example:

```
var mysql = require('promise-mysql');
var connection;

mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'sauron',
    password: 'theonetruering',
    database: 'mordor'
}).then(function(conn){
    connection = conn;
});
```

and in your web service:

```
return connection.query('insert into a values(. . . . .)')
    .then(function(rows){
        var a_id = rows.insertId;
        return connection.query('insert into b values(. . . . .)')
            .then(function(rows){
                return connection.query('insert into c values(. . . . .)');
            });
    });
```

You can actually chain at the end of the first `.then(function(rows){})`, but I just wanted to make sure that a_id won't exist out of where you insert into tables b and c.